# Unable to connect to psql console: psql: FATAL: Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to connect to psql console with `psql -U postgres` but keep getting the following Error:

```
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

This if the content on pg_hba.conf

```
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Peer authentication requires you to be that user, are you logged in as the postgres user e.g. `sudo su - postgres` -> `psql`

Comment: i'm not @Lucas. Would change postgres user config to md5 work as well?

Comment: If no md5 password has been set you will not be able to use it, you should change user to postgres in the operating system and then assign superuser roles from there.